# Deploy a pushed image builded in jenkins docker container in the host of the jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am running jenkins in docker. I have created a pipeline inside this image that downloads the source code of my app, compiles it, builds the Docker image, and pushes it to Docker Hub. These steps already work. Now, I would like to deploy the application on the host machine where the Docker image for Jenkins is running. I have a working `docker-compose.yml` file, but how can I communicate with the host machine to trigger a command like `docker-compose run`

I have read about Docker sockets and Docker network IP addresses, but I don't understand how they work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to build your application image in a job that runs in your slave node, then deploy that image in your host node?

In that case, why not create a new Jenkins job that is forced to run on the host as the agent. Then, at the end of the job that builds and deploys the image to DockerHub, you can trigger this build. Since the downstream job is forced to run on the host node, there is no need for sockets or additional configuration.

Comment: Do you have and example? I am lost.